# Must algebraic extensions of the same degree have subfields of the same degree?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb F$ be a field and let $\mathbb K_1$ and $\mathbb K_2$ be finite extensions of $\mathbb F$ with the same degree, that is, $[\mathbb K_1:\mathbb F]=[\mathbb K_2:\mathbb F]$. Now, assume that $\mathbb K_1$ contains a subfield of degree $s$ over $\mathbb F$. My question is: Can we conclude that also $\mathbb K_2$  contains a subfield of degree $s$ over $\mathbb F$?

If the field $\mathbb F$ is finite, then this is true, since we can  embedded $\mathbb K_1$ and $\mathbb K_2$ in the matrix ring $M_m(\mathbb F)$, where $m=[\mathbb K_1:\mathbb F]=[\mathbb K_2:\mathbb F]$ and it can be proved that there is an inner authomorphism of $M_m(\mathbb F)$ that apply $\mathbb K_1$ in $\mathbb K_2$.

Comment: If the field $\mathbf F$ is finite then it is true because any finite extension of degree $d$ is a splitting field of $x^{q^d}-x$ over $\mathbf F$, where $q$ is the size of $\mathbf F$, and two splitting fields of the same polynomial over the same field are isomorphic by an isomorphism fixing that base field. That is the more conventional explanation than an argument with matrix rings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F=\mathbb{Q}$. Let $K_1$ be the splitting field of $f_1=x^4+8x+12$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $K_2$ be the splitting field of $f_2=x^{12}+x^{11}+\cdots+x+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (this is just the $13$th cyclotomic polynomial). Then
$$[K_1:F]=[K_2:F]=12$$
However, $\mathrm{Gal}(K_1/F)\cong A_4$ and $\mathrm{Gal}(K_2/F)\cong\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, and recall that $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ has a subgroup of size $6$, while $A_4$ does not. Therefore, by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, there is an intermediate field $K_2\supset L_2\supset F$ with $[L_2:F]=2$, but there is no intermediate field $K_1\supset L_1\supset F$ with $[L_1:F]=2$.

(For my claim that $\mathrm{Gal}(K_1/F)\cong A_4$, see [p.6 of this article by Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf).)

Comment: Good. It’s really a question of group theory, and you only need to get a pair of fields with the right groups.